# How to combine customized Twitter Bootstrap and H5BP?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, html5boilerplate

I am looking for a best practices to combine between **customized** Twitter Bootstrap and H5BP (HTML5 Boilerplate) .
I've tried to use this shell script to quickly setup a project at this [link](https://gist.github.com/1422879) and [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) generator.

*Ps: Customization consist in choosing the color and size... using Twitter Bootstrap customize variables*

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: What's wrong with Initializr?

Comment: No wrong with Initializr :) juste i need to customize my template (link color, width & height size, ... ) using for example [twitter bootstrap customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) and combine it with H5BP i think use shell script is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

I do

`git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git`.

Make some change in less files in `less/*.less`

You might want to change some values in `variables.less`

And Run `make bootstrap` in git cloned folder.

It will create `bootstrap` folder in your bootstrap folder.

Use that files in created `bootstrap` folder.

Comment: Thank you, bu your solution is the same if I used this http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html
Ok, this is first step. Now, how to combine it with H5BP, knowing that H5BP use Jquiry and normalize for reset ..?

Comment: @AmineHADDAD I actually use `head.js` to load `H5BP`, `jQuery` and etc asynchronously

Comment: Thank you @InspiredJW but this is not what I'm looking and "This project is unmaintained. See projects like Modernizr, RequireJS, .." [source](https://github.com/headjs/headjs) :)

Comment: "This project is unmaintained" -> "Rebooting HeadJS" https://github.com/headjs/headjs